# Donde se ecuentra el directorio /conf en ws02?

Tags: wso2

estoy tratando de implmentar WS02 como consumer de una cola de rabbitmq y en repetidas ocaciones la documentacion hace referencia a un archivo deployment.toml pero no lorgro econtrar el directorio /conf que es donde se supone irira dicho archivo, alguien conoce este direcotorio? De antemano muchas gracias.

Adjunto imagen de la referencia en la doc
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Adjunto imagen de mi los directorios en mi proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrias por favor mirar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y tambien ver [ask]???

Comment: @gbianchi Podrias por favor darme feedback de que esta mal con mi pregunta, ya habia visto el articulo de como preguntar y lo segui para hacer esta consulta, no se que pordria, estar omitiendo, Gracias.

Comment: te fijaste si no esta hablando de la configuracion de la cola (que por tu print, es de lo que parece hablar?).. esta pregunta no tiene nada malo.. pero nos damos cuenta que no viste el recorrido y por lo tanto, supones que no viste como mejorar tus preguntas para que realmente reciban respuesta, o aquellas que tienen respuestas, aceptarlas de corresponder o pedir las aclaraciones del caso...